# Character Constants and Initialization in C

Tags: c, char, int, constants

I'm learning the C language with a book called 'C Primer Plus'. Currently, I'm reading about C data types (chapter 3) and have a question.

In the book, it is written that

> #### Character Constants and Initialization
>
> [...]  A single character contained between single quotes is a C character constant. [...] Because characters are really stored as numeric values, you can also use the numerical code to assign values. [...] Somewhat oddly, C treats character constants as type int rather than type char. For example, on an ASCII system with a 32-bit int and an 8-bit char, the code
>
> ```
> char grade = 'B';
> ```
>
> represents 'B' as the numerical value 66 stored in a 32-bit unit, but grade winds up with 66 stored in an 8-bit unit.

How I understood this part was that the declare statement `char grade = 'B';` will store its char variable and character constant in two places, one as the numerical value 66 in a 32-bit unit and the variable `grade` with 66 in an 8-bit unit. (This was a bit confusing.) Then the very next two sentences in the book are:

> This characteristic of character constants makes it possible to define a character constant such as 'FATE', with four separate 8-bit ASCII codes stored in a 32-bit unit. However, attempting to assign such a character constant to a char variable results in only the last 8 bits being used, so the variable gets the value 'E'.

What I understood here is that a multi-character constant is possible, unlike the definition the book gave at the beginning. However, it is possible with only one of two places they mentioned in the last part. Because character constants are type `int` in C, and `int` is 32 bits here, 'FATE' has 4 characters with 8 bits each; therefore, 4 * 8 = 32. but a char variable has only 8 bits of space, so the only last letter will be stored.

And, to apply the knowledge, I tried

```
/* test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char grade = 'FATE';
    printf("%d, %c", grade, grade);
    return 0;
}
```

This gave me some warnings when compiling. The warnings were multi-character character constant and overflow in implicit constant conversion.

Then I tried 'FAT', 'FA', and 'F'. Only 'F' worked.

Finally, my questions are:

1. Am I understanding the book correctly? Does Initializing char variable w/ a character constant need two places to save its value?
2. If I'm right, Why does it separate the numerical value and char variable? How does it exactly separate and connect together when it's called?  why does it need two places?
3. If I'm right, did my test.c fail w/ multi-character character constants because the `int` unit of my laptop system is only an 8-bit byte?

Comment: The order of multi-character constants is implementation-dependent.

Comment: *'FATE' has 4 characters with 8 byte each, therefore, 4 * 8 = 32. but a char variable has only 8 byte space, so the only last letter will be stored.* – BITS, not bytes

Comment: Try adding `int igrade = 'FATE';` and then change to: `printf("%d, %c", igrade, grade);` - you will see the ***full int*** value for `igrade`. Trying to print a `char` as an `int` doesn't work.

Comment: You are confused about the first part; `'B'` is an `int` constant however it does not occupy any storage yet . The point is that the code `char grade = 'B'` is exactly the same as `char grade = 66` (supposing your system uses ASCII encoding, that is).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Your edit is amazing. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, you're right. That's my mistake.

Comment: @AdrianMole Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @M.M Hm, okay. I understand that 'B' is the same is 66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'B'` is a *value* of type `int`, but it is not stored anywhere, just like 42 is not stored anywhere, it is a number. However, if you **write 42 on paper** in decimal it will take 2 digits of space on the paper. If you've got 42 apples, the number 42 need not be written down and it doesn't therefore consume space, but you still have 42 apples...

Now a `char grade` is an *object*. An integer value of type `char` - an integer of small magnitude (usually -128 ... 127, 0 ... 255) can be stored into `grade`.

An object is like a field in a paper form where you can write a certain length of text. A `char` on a form would have enough space only for a number in that range.
Since ASCII `'B'` has value 66, it conveniently fits into the range of `char`.

An object of type `int` could store an integer of possibly larger magnitude (perhaps -32768 ... 32767, or -2147483648 ... 2147483647; that is *implementation-defined*).

---

Then we come to the multicharacter constants. Unlike the book claims, the C standard states ([C11 6.4.4.4p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10)) that

> [...] The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab') [...] is implementation-defined. [...]

i.e. an implementation (the C compiler) can define the value of `FATE` as it seems fit. The author incorrectly claims that the value need to be that of `'F' * 16777216 + 'A' * 65536 + 'T' * 256 + 'E'`, but the C standard requires no such thing. This is the reason why many compilers will warn about the use of multicharacter constants (in your case you got *"warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]"*)* - because they're not *portable* i.e. the same code will not behave in the same manner when compiled with different compilers.

Now, we assume that `'FATE'` indeed results in that number, i.e. 1178686533. Now how would *you* write that number 121686533 in a form in a field where you can only write a number between -128 ... 127? Again the behaviour is *implementation-defined*. The author's implementation will take that number modulo 256, which will result in `69`, which is the ASCII code of the `E` letter, but the exact behaviour is again up to the compiler implementation.

To warn about that implementation-defined behaviour, compiler spat out something like *warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '1178686533' to '69'*.

---

The main takeaway from this is: if you intend to store the last letter of word `FATE` in `char grade`, you do it like this:

```
char grade = 'E';
```

The way how author does it can plausibly result in some compiler grading the authors book with grade `F`...

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation. So declaring a variable is like making an object and that object has a field like paper where I can write a value. Depends on the type of a variable, the available space is different. Also depends on the type of a value, the needed space to store is different. In case of a multi-character constant, how the value will be stored is decided by the compiler being used.

Comment: Yes, a character constant is always of type int, how the value in that int is formed is decided by the compiler in case of a multicharacter code. The standard specifies only how it happens for a single char one.

Answer (score 0):

1. the computer will only recognize the binary code, the character constants will not be stored in both places because they are the same binary code in the computer.
2. as above.
3. the computer treats the character constants as type int, but really stores them as one byte of the size of char, so only one byte is saved (in your computer it's F, which is of course stored in binary form). When printed, %c tells the computer to output the content as a character, and the F is finally displayed.
   My English is not very good. Feel free to discuss.

---

First, you need to understand the literal constants.Often, we use a suffix to tell the computer what type of literal constant the literal constant belongs to.
like，`123` `10LLU` `999L`.
Character constant is one of the literal constants.

The C  treats all character constants as `int` type(But it's not actually stored in memory yet).And the type of variable declared determines the size of the storage space.

```
char c = 'abc';
```

The computer considers `abc` as an int type, but char is only one byte in size, so the last thing stored is 'c'(or 'a', depending on your complier)

```
printf("%c", character);
```

At last, C treat all literal constants as `int` type(or unsigned int, long int ....).But, But the details of storage still depend on the declared type.